# SELECT DISTINCT and TRIM on the fly

Tags: postgresql, distinct

I need to select some string from DB. The problem is that those strings are stored in DB in some inconvenient way. For example I have:

```
| "Kraków" 
| "Kraków&nbsp;" 
| "KRAKÓW"
```

I have to get only single name of the city - in this case: "Kraków". City names are stored in a few tables.

I tryied something like that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(LOWER(TRIM(city_name, '&nbsp;'))) FROM cities_object UNION DISTINCT
        SELECT DISTINCT(LOWER(TRIM(city_name, '&nbsp;'))) FROM cities_firms UNION  DISTINCT 
        SELECT DISTINCT(LOWER(TRIM(city_name, '&nbsp;'))) FROM cities_other UNION  DISTINCT 
        WHERE
            published = '1'
```

But this don't work. I think this is becouse SQL cant do it "on the fly". Any ideas?

Comment: Consider rephrasing and clarifying your question. It's not clear what you're up to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just created test DB and your code almost works!

Try to check several things:

- inside trim function: &nbsp, but in your data example: ;nbsp
- WHERE condition (published = '1') only for third table (cities_other)
- too much "distinct" statements ;)

Did you mean:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(LOWER(TRIM(city_name, '&nbsp'))) FROM cities_object WHERE published = '1'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT(LOWER(TRIM(city_name, '&nbsp'))) FROM cities_firms WHERE published = '1'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT(LOWER(TRIM(city_name, '&nbsp'))) FROM cities_other WHERE published = '1';
```

?

...and if this still won't help, try to give us error message you get. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct
    lower(
        regexp_replace(city_name, '^&nbsp;|&nbsp;$', '', 'g')
    ) city_name
from (
    select city_name from cities_object
    where published = '1'
    union
    select city_name from cities_firms
    where published = '1'
    union
    select city_name from cities_other
    where published = '1'
) s
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT replace(lower(city_name), ';nbsp', '') AS city_name
FROM  (
    SELECT city_name FROM cities_object WHERE published = '1'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT city_name FROM cities_firms  WHERE published = '1'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT city_name FROM cities_other  WHERE published = '1'
    ) sub
GROUP  BY 1
```

[`replace()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) removes any occurrence of `;nbsp` anywhere in the string. It's not as powerful as `regexp_replace()`, but a lot faster. Place it *after* `lower()` to replace `;NBSP` also.
But are you sure your artefact is `;nbsp`, not `&nbsp;`?

While `UNION` makes sense to collect data from three source tables, since you want to eliminate duplicates anyway, it may be faster to use [`UNION ALL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-UNION) and eliminate duplicates ***once*** in the final `GROUP BY` (or `DISTINCT`) step. Depends on existing indices, the number of duplicates and data distribution.
You can test performance with [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html).

Comment: If the subquery produces `Name` and `name` you will finish with two `name`s

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: No, `GROUP BY` takes care of that. Your query collapses duplicates twice (as does cathulhu's query).

Answer (score 0):

Use a wildcard.

```
WHERE FirstName LIKE LOWER('Kraków%')
```

Comment: I have to select all rows without condition like that. Kraków is just example.